# Retrieve choice name rather than value

Tags: r, shiny

I have a named `choices` slot in `selectInput`, and would like to retrieve the name associated with the choice, rather than the value.

MWE:

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("foo",
                label = "Select choice here:",
                choices = c("Choice 1" = "Choice1",
                            "Choice 2" = "Choice2",
                            "Choice 3" = "Choice3"),
                selected = "Choice1",
                multiple = TRUE),
    textOutput("nameOfChoice")
  ),
  mainPanel()),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$nameOfChoice = renderText(input$foo[1])
  }
)
```

Which produces:

[image]

Instead, I would like the text output to read `Choice 1`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put your choices in an object in `global.R` and then use it in both `server.R` and `ui.R`.

In `global.R`:

```
fooChoices<-c("Choice 1" = "Choice1",
                        "Choice 2" = "Choice2",
                        "Choice 3" = "Choice3")
```

In `ui.R`:

```
selectInput("foo",
            label = "Select choice here:",
            choices = fooChoices)
```

In `server.R`:

```
output$nameOfChoice = renderText(names(fooChoices[fooChoices==input$foo]))
```

Comment: While a reasonable solution, this is cumbersome because this passes the burden of keeping track of the choice vector and the input object slotname to me -- I would rather Shiny did this.

Comment: I don't get your comment. You just give a symbol to the choice vector. That's it. What exactly do you think is cumbersome?

Comment: Thanks for your answer -- given that there are no better answers, I will mark this as accepted.