# How to access choiceNames of UI Inputs in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I've a shinyApp with radio buttons UI. These buttons are a named vector. `input$radioInputs` returns value of selection. How can I access the names as well, i.e., get output `Your choice is a and value 1`?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    radioButtons(inputId = "radioInputs",
                 label = "Choose radio inputs",
                 choiceNames = letters[1:3],
                 choiceValues = 1:3,
                 # choiceNames and choiceValues can be replaced with
                 # choices = c("a"=1, "b"=2, "c"=3)
                 selected = "a")  ),
  mainPanel(
    textOutput("outputText")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$outputText <- renderText({
    paste("Your choice is", input$radioInputs)
  }

  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29732359/5894457) is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `outputext` by this does the trick:

```
  output$outputText <- renderText({
    paste("Your choice is", 
        letters[as.numeric(input$radioInputs)],
        "and the value",
        input$radioInputs)
  }
```

Also, `selected = 1` in the `radioButtons` initializes the value properly :)

Comment: Apparently it works only when names are letters.

Comment: Which is the case here. So, did it answer your question?