# Download multiple checkboxes in a single csv file via downloadhandler- R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

I'm attempting to create a list of checkboxes where a user can select what they want to download in a single csv file and the csv file should display both 'choiceNames' and 'choiceValues', which defined in the code. I wrote the code below, but the download button does not work, and I don't know how to solve this issue

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(h1(" Worksheet",align="center")),
  hr(),
  
  sidebarPanel(  
    titlePanel(h4("Antenatal Risk Factors/Current Pregnancy",align="center")),
    hr(),
    checkboxGroupInput("Antel", "  ",
                       choiceNames =
                         list("Urinary tract infections this pregnancy",
                              "Urinary tract infections this pregnancy, treated",
                              "Anemia this pregnancy (HCT < 30/Hgb <10)",
                              "Hemoglobinopathy this pregnancy",
                              "Coagulation disorder",
                              "Rh sensitization",
                              "Other iso-immunization",
                              "Biliary/liver disorder(Yes at delivery)",
                              "Cardiac disease",
                              "Autoimmune disease",
                              "Antiphospholipid syndrome",
                              "Specify collagen vascular disease",
                              "Asthma",
                              "Acute or chronic lung disease",
                              "Renal disorder/disease",
                              "Renal dialysis or end stage renal disease",
                              "Thyroid disease",
                              "Cancer this pregnancy",
                              "Cancer treatment this pregnancy"
                         ),
                       choiceValues =list("RFC_INFUT","RFC_INFUTTX",
                                          "RFC_ANEMIA",
                                          "RFC_HEMO",
                                          "COAGULATION_DISORDER",
                                          "RFC_RHS",
                                          "RFC_ISO",
                                          "BILARY_LIVE_DISORD",
                                          "RFC_CDDZ",
                                          "RFC_CVDZ",
                                          "RFC_APSY",
                                          "RFC_CVSPEC",
                                          "RFC_ASTH",
                                          "RFC_LGDZ",
                                          "RENAL_DISORDER_DISEASE",
                                          "RFC_RNDY",
                                          "RFC_THYDZ",
                                          "RFC_CA",
                                          "CANCER_TREATMENT" )
    ),  

   
    
    checkboxGroupInput("Fetal", "Fetal Conditions",
                       choiceNames = list("Decreased fetal movement",
                                          "Abnormal fetal heart rate/rhythm",
                                          "Suspected IUGR this pregnancy",
                                          "Fetal compromise this pregnancy",
                                          "Suspected Fetal CNS Anomaly",
                                          "Diagnosed fetal anomaly:",
                                          "Fetal damage",
                                          "Postterm, > 41 6/7 weeks"),
                       choiceValues = list("RFC_FETMOV",
                                           "RFC_ABRHY","RFC_IUGR",
                                           "RFC_FCOMP",
                                           "RFC_FEANOM",
                                           "RFC_FAN",
                                           "RFC_FD",
                                           "RFC_POST")
                       
                       
    ), 
 checkboxGroupInput("Maternal", "Maternal Characteristics",
                     choiceNames = list("Maternal traumatic injury during this pregnancy",
                                  "Domestic violence during this pregnancy",
                                  "aternal surgical procedure during this pregnancy",
                              "Other antenatal risk factors during this pregnancy:_____"),
                     choiceValues = list("RFC_TINJ",
                                           "RFC_VIOL",
                                           "RFC_SURG",
                                           "RFC_OTHR")
    ), 
    
  )
 downloadButton("download") 
  #______________END_______________#   
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$download_checkboxes <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      "results.csv"
    },
    content = function(file) {
      Data <- data.frame(selected = input$Antel & input$Fetal )
      write.csv(Data, file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
  
  
}
)
 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Try `downloadButton("download_checkboxes","Download")`. Also there's a missing coma right before the `downloadButton()` and an extra parenthesis in the server function.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I still can't download multiple choices in a single csv file where the csv file should display both 'choiceNames' and 'choiceValues'

Comment: the values of `input$Antel` only is only `choiceValues`. Most solutions on SO for accessing the `choiceNames` on the server side, point to storing your selection in a global variable, then retrieving the "name" when you need it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732099/retrieve-choice-name-rather-than-value

Comment: I want choice names and choice value in different column in the file. for instance, Col1 :"Urinary tract infections this pregnancy"  and col2 : "RFC_INFUT" when the user checked Urinary tract infections this pregnancy in the App

Comment: The link provided shows you how to do that.

Comment: the link you provide is work only if I want to download the checkbox groups separately (I tried it).  in this question I want to be able to download all of the checkboxGroup Inputs: Antel & Fetal & Maternal in one button with showing the names and values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
library(shiny)

c_antel <- data.frame(cn = c("Urinary tract infections this pregnancy",
                             "Urinary tract infections this pregnancy, treated",
                             "Anemia this pregnancy (HCT < 30/Hgb <10)",
                             "Hemoglobinopathy this pregnancy",
                             "Coagulation disorder",
                             "Rh sensitization",
                             "Other iso-immunization",
                             "Biliary/liver disorder(Yes at delivery)",
                             "Cardiac disease",
                             "Autoimmune disease",
                             "Antiphospholipid syndrome",
                             "Specify collagen vascular disease",
                             "Asthma",
                             "Acute or chronic lung disease",
                             "Renal disorder/disease",
                             "Renal dialysis or end stage renal disease",
                             "Thyroid disease",
                             "Cancer this pregnancy",
                             "Cancer treatment this pregnancy"),
                      cv = c("RFC_INFUT",
                             "RFC_INFUTTX",
                             "RFC_ANEMIA",
                             "RFC_HEMO",
                             "COAGULATION_DISORDER",
                             "RFC_RHS",
                             "RFC_ISO",
                             "BILARY_LIVE_DISORD",
                             "RFC_CDDZ",
                             "RFC_CVDZ",
                             "RFC_APSY",
                             "RFC_CVSPEC",
                             "RFC_ASTH",
                             "RFC_LGDZ",
                             "RENAL_DISORDER_DISEASE",
                             "RFC_RNDY",
                             "RFC_THYDZ",
                             "RFC_CA",
                             "CANCER_TREATMENT"))

c_fetal <- data.frame(cn = c("Decreased fetal movement",
                             "Abnormal fetal heart rate/rhythm",
                             "Suspected IUGR this pregnancy",
                             "Fetal compromise this pregnancy",
                             "Suspected Fetal CNS Anomaly",
                             "Diagnosed fetal anomaly:",
                             "Fetal damage",
                             "Postterm, > 41 6/7 weeks"),
                      cv = c("RFC_FETMOV",
                             "RFC_ABRHY","RFC_IUGR",
                             "RFC_FCOMP",
                             "RFC_FEANOM",
                             "RFC_FAN",
                             "RFC_FD",
                             "RFC_POST"))

c_mater <- data.frame(cn = c("Maternal traumatic injury during this pregnancy",
                              "Domestic violence during this pregnancy",
                             "aternal surgical procedure during this pregnancy",
                             "Other antenatal risk factors during this pregnancy:_____"),
                      cv = c("RFC_TINJ",
                            "RFC_VIOL",
                            "RFC_SURG",
                            "RFC_OTHR"))
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(h1(" Worksheet",align="center")),
  hr(),
  
  sidebarPanel(  
    titlePanel(h4("Antenatal Risk Factors/Current Pregnancy",align="center")),
    hr(),
    checkboxGroupInput("Antel", "  ",
                       choiceNames = c_antel$cn,
                       choiceValues = c_antel$cv
    ),  
    checkboxGroupInput("Fetal", "Fetal Conditions",
                       choiceNames = c_fetal$cn,
                       choiceValues = c_fetal$cv
    ), 
    checkboxGroupInput("Maternal", "Maternal Characteristics",
                       choiceNames = c_mater$cn,
                       choiceValues = c_mater$cv
    )
  ),
  downloadButton("download_checkboxes", "download"),
  #______________END_______________#   
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$download_checkboxes <- downloadHandler(
    contentType = "text/csv",
    filename = "results.csv",
    content = function(file) {
      Data <- data.frame(
        key = c(input$Antel, 
                input$Fetal,
                input$Maternal),
        value = c(c_antel$cn[c_antel$cv %in% input$Antel],
                  c_fetal$cn[c_fetal$cv %in% input$Fetal],
                  c_mater$cn[c_mater$cv %in% input$Maternal])
        )
      write.csv(Data, file, row.names = F)
    }
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```